# SSIS no-match lookup? SQL server integration services - prevent duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration

In ssis 2012, let's presume I simply copy customer data from one DB Source to a DB Destination (both are different database instances, one cannot "see" the other).
How do I prevent adding customer data I already added before. In other words, when I rerun the task, it should not add the customer twice or more (only the ones that previously failed). We have a non-unique reference available in the destination customer table e.g. 'SourceCustomerID' which is non-unique!
So we cannot rely on some unique index in the Destination table(s), and if we could, I don't want go this way (would cause failures)...

Added based on questions below: there ARE columns that uniquely identify data in the target table, and we need these for this, but these are nor implemented as unique indexes, nor do I want to let the job (or rows) fail like this. I want to prevent adding these rows in a controlled way.

I tried the lookup component, playing with "Lookup No Match Output", etc...no luck yet.

Any ideas how to accomplish this using the SSIS principles??

Best regards
Bart.

Comment: I read your question as "How do I prevent duplicates when I have nothing that uniquely identifies a duplicate?" Surely, that's not what you're asking

Comment: Do you mean that there isn't a single field, but a combination of multiple fields that makes the row unique?

Comment: Thank you for responding. There is a field that uniquely identifies a duplicate, but this field is not a unique constraint. But if it were, I want to silently skip (or log in a friendly way) when there is a match.

When there are errors in the processing, I want to fix these, and rerun without creating duplicates (which is now happening).

Comment: You should actually be able to use the lookup component to do this. What is the actual issue you have with this approach?

Comment: I want to add when there is a "no match"...I want to do nothing when there is a match...it appears to work, but it ends up adding duplicates

Comment: Keep in mind the lookup component is case sensitive. If you are matching on numeric keys to identify duplicates and using the no match output then it should operate as expected. You'll need to do some more investigation and give us more information.

Comment: It is a numeric comparison. And it doesnt work. In some way understandable, because it is only lookup functionality. I tried to abuse it to prevent inserts of duplicates...it doesnt work like that. The SCD (which I thought was overkill) is the component with which this can be implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SCD component 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141715.aspx

You map the business key which will check for existing record and you can insert/update.  You can alter it to insert only.

Comment: This is, based on the specifications I read so far, what can do the job. Thanks.